# How to see the video from the webcam on the laptop?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, webcam

I have a webcam built in to my laptop.  Is there a way to show the video in a window?

I'm using Windows 8.1.

Comment: [VLC](https://www.videolan.org) or [Media Player Classic](https://mpc-hc.org/) will both do what you want.  Other than that, check with your Webcam vendor.

Comment: I use [YouCam](http://www.cyberlink.com/products/youcam/). For me it's perfect. You can see also other features on their website.

Answer (score 3):

#### How do I see the video from the webcam on the laptop?

You can use the [Windows Camera App](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/camera/1f9239de-0aab-489b-85f3-379e82e34820).

---

#### What is the Windows Camera App?

> **Description**
>
> The Camera app captures your life's moments. Take Photos, Record
>   Videos and browse through them to share the best ones out with your
>   friends and family
>
> **Features**
>
> - Take Photos and crop them to get your best shots
> - Record Videos and trim them to create the clip you want
> - Share your memories with friends and family

Source [Windows Camera App](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/camera/1f9239de-0aab-489b-85f3-379e82e34820)

---

#### How do I record a Video?

> If your PC has a built-in camera or a connected webcam, you can use
>   the Camera app to take photos and videos.
>
> **Open the Camera app**
>
> There are a few different ways to open the Camera app. If you're on
>   Start, you can use the tile. If you're using other apps or are in the
>   desktop, you can search for the app and open it from the search
>   results. You can also open the Camera app right from the lock screen
>   when you want to take a quick picture without signing in first.
>
> If you're on Start
>
> - Tap or click the Camera tile.
>
> If you're using another app or the desktop
>
> 1. Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, and then tap Search.
>      (If you're using a mouse, point to the lower-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer up, and then click Search.)
> 2. Enter Camera in the search box, and then tap or click Camera in the results.
>
> **To take a video**
>
> - In the Camera app, tap or click the Video button Video button to start recording. Tap or click it again to stop recording.
> - If you want to see the video, drag the screen to the right or click the left arrow.

Source [Camera app and webcams help](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/camera-app-faq)

Answer (score -1):

An other Windows 8.1 App, besides Camera App, is Photo Booth Pro, it gives you a Mac Photo Booth like set of filters or "special effects", it's free but has ads.

[Photo Booth Pro](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/photo-booth-pro/1715c97d-f72a-4caf-b84c-ede989f1186b)